# Getting PulseAudio to automatically use the default remote sink when waking up

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pulse-audio

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I set PulseAudio (PA) on a remote machine on LAN to be the sink of my PC.

This works pretty well. However, if I suspend my PC and then wake it up (some hours later), the default audio sink falls back to HDMI, or whatever is available locally.

Now after some seconds the network starts up and the remote PA sink appears, but it won't be selected as default. I need to manually select it every time when I wake my PC from suspended.

The problem is that PA assigns a new ID to the same sink every time after wake up, so there is no way to set the default to a constant ID.

I can write a simple C++ program that listens to PA events and then reacts, but I want to know if there is any other easier / faster method to always use the remote sink when it is present.